# Why doesnt my div respond to bottom and left

Tags: html, css

I've got a div inside another div. And I want it placed in the bottom left corner of the red box, but it doesn't respond to: `bottom:0; left:0;`.

It's the green box.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z4bhhbp6/1/)

**EDIT:**
I'm so oblivious.

Comment: position of the parent element

Comment: Try this Just add a position:relative to `.portfoliotekst` and change the `position:relative` to `positio:absolute`to viewwebsite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.portfoliotekst {
    padding-top:1px;
    top:0;
    width:300px;
    height: 340px;
    background-color:red;
    position:relative; /* add this to specify its position */
}
.viewwebsite {
    text-align:center;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    margin-top:50px;
    line-height:56px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:#81b63a;
    position:relative;
    font-size:14pt;
    position:absolute; /* add this to specify its position wrt its parent */
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z4bhhbp6/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.portfolioitem{
 margin-top:11px;
 width:100%;
    height:auto;
    border-bottom:5px solid #000;
}

.borderbottom{
 margin-top:20px;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #8cc63f;
}

.portfolioimg{ display:inline-block; }

.portfolioitem img{
 display:block;
 height:340px;
 width:331px;
}
.portfolioinfo{
 display:inline-block;
    background-color:yellow;
 height:340px;
    width:560px;
}
 .portfoliotekst{
        padding-top:1px;
  top:0;
        width:300px;
    height: 340px;
    background-color:red;
      position : relative;
}
 .viewwebsite{
  text-align:center;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
        margin-top:50px;
  line-height:56px;
  width:200px;
  background-color:#81b63a;
  position:absolute;
  font-size:14pt;
 }

 #page-main .viewwebsite a{
  color:#fff !important;
  text-decoration:none;
 }

.centertekst{ margin:0 auto; }
.topmargin { margin-top:40px; }
.left{ float: left; }
.right{ float: right; }
```

```html
<h2 class="borderbottom">MET Heerhugowaard</h2>
<div class="portfolioitem">
 <div class="portfolioimg left">
  <img src="/images/methhw.png" height="680" width="663"/>
 </div>
 <div class="portfolioinfo">
  <div class="portfoliotekst centertekst">
   <h2>Beschrijving</h2>
   Insert beschrijving here
   
   <h2>Technieken</h2>
   Insert Technieken here
            <div class="viewwebsite">
                <a href="">Bekijk de website</a>
            </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Remember when you need to do something similar :

- **Container** is the one with `relative` position
- **Contained** is the one with `absolute` position

Have fun with CSS !